# Composite, Functions Application Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried to do this question, but I could not understand, let alone to do it.
The Volume V of a right circular cone is $$ V= \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h $$ . If the height is twice the radius, express the volume V as a function of r.
If I can get some explanation along with solving it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h = 2r$. Substitute in the equation. $V = \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 (2r)$. Simplifying: $V = \frac{2}{3} \pi r^3$.

We let $h = 2r$ because $h$ denotes the height, and $r$ denotes the radius. This equation means the height is twice the radius.

Answer (score 1):

The height is twice the radius means that the height is equal to the radius taken two times: $h=2r$. So, now we know that $h$ is equivalent to $2r$. Expressing the volume $V$ as a function of $r$ means that the only variable the volume $V$ depends on should be $r$. This means that we need to get rid of $h$ in that expression by replacing it with what it is equivalent to, that is, $2r$ and then do some basic algebra to simplify our result:

$$
V= \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h=
\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 (2r)=
\frac{2}{3}\pi r^{2+1}=
\frac{2}{3}\pi r^3.
$$

The volume $V$ is now expressed as a function of one variable which, in this case, is $r$.